# Is there a way to hide the GlobalNav on the Homepage using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

as the question states I would like to only show the GlobalNav on the work details page. Seems like this should be possible but I can't figure it out. Any tips out there? I am using React for the front end and Strapi for the back end.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <div className="App">
          <GlobalNav />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
            <Route path="/workdetails/:id" element={<WorkDetails />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: just put it inside `WorkDetails`? also you can search for `Outlet` in router